# Is the Wilcoxon Rank-sum test the best option with many near 0 values >0?

Tags: wilcoxon-signed-rank, paired-comparisons

I have a two very large datasets. They look something like this, but with a few thousand rows. They are the total number of tyrosines in a short DNA sequence with a length of up to 5. A would precede an interesting feature in the sequence, whilst B follows it. A null hypothesis would be that there is no difference in the occurrence of tyrosines before or after the middle sequence.

```
| X | A | B |
|---|---|---|
| a | 0 | 1 |
| b | 2 | 2 |
| c | 1 | 4 |
| d | 0 | 3 |
```

*Where X is a given feature, A is how many tyrosines are in the 5 residues before the feature, and B is how many tyrosines are in the 5 residues after the feature.*

I'm comparing the difference between A and B. Normally, it would be a no-brainer to use a non-parametric test like the [Wilcoxon Rank-sum test](https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~wild/ChanceEnc/Ch10.wilcoxon.pdf). However, the minimum and the maximum value of any given value is 0 and 5 respectively. The linked chapter describes:

> If one is primarily interested in differences in location between the
>   two distributions, the Wilcoxon test has the disadvantage of also
>   reacting to other differences between the distributions such as
>   differences in shape.

So although the data *might* be similarly distributed, the shapes will be different if say set A is distributed with a mean of 1 since values cannot go below 0, and set B with a mean of 3, which if the datasets a similarly distributed, would have less values clumped at 0.

Another test option would be a [paired T-test](http://support.minitab.com/en-us/minitab/17/topic-library/basic-statistics-and-graphs/hypothesis-tests/tests-of-means/why-use-paired-t/) which is less affected by variance, however assumes that the underlying distribution is also symmetric (nope), unimodal (not necessarily), and continuous (nope, the scale is integers between 0 and 5).

**In short:** What is the most powerful statistical test for paired, discrete, non-symmetric, large datasets, where the values have upper and lower limits?

*Apologies for the inevitable jargon blunders, I have no formal training in statistics!*

Comment: What do the values 0, 1,2,3,4,5 refer to? 
What is the scientific question you are trying to answer?
Are the two values on each row matched or paired?

Comment: @HarveyMotulsky Thanks for clarifying. I've updated the question to hopefully include the relevant scientific design. I've been assuming they're paired, but perhaps A and B are simply matched. What do you think?

Comment: "Similarly distributed" implies "similar shapes."  This suggests you may be worrying about nothing.

Comment: @whuber I am worried that for example if they were both distributed similarly, say A=[-2,-1,0,1,2,3], and B=[0,1,2,3,4,5], in real values the "shape" would look differently: A=[0,0,0,1,2,3] and B=[0,1,2,3,4,5]. I imagine I have misunderstood something fundamental and am making a fuss out of nothing.